# React - Render a certain number of components dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, state, material-ui

I would like to display a number of the component Star (MUI component) based on the number of points the user has earned (`this.state.points`).

I don't know how to do this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Star } from "@material-ui/icons";

Points extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      points: 6
    };
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <p>
           + {this.state.points} points
           <Star />
         </p>
       </div>
     );
    }
  }

export default Points;
```

Comment: Iterate and return components? It's not clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: which is version of material-ui?

Comment: Points should be a class.

Comment: I'd like 6 stars displayed, it's a "class", I made a mistake while copy-pasting, and it's the latest version of material-ui

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to create new Array with `this.state.points` number of empty slots which you then fill with the `<Star />` component like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Star } from "@material-ui/icons";

class Points extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      points: 6
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          + {this.state.points} points
          // This is where the magic happens
          {Array(this.state.points).fill(<Star />)}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Points;
```

Here is a working Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/vj3xpyn0x0

Comment: nice solution  

Comment: nice solution, but your sandbox is not working currently due to import { Star } from "@material-ui/icons";

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Star } from "@material-ui/icons";

Points extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  points: 6
 };
}

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <p>
       + {this.state.points} points

       {Array.from(Array(this.state.points)).map((x, index) => <Star key={index} />)}
     </p>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default Points;
```

Comment: We are creating a array with length of points. `Array(n)` return a empty array and `Array.from` create array where we can execute all array prototypes. as we should have key for all array element in react, we are using `map` function.

Comment: Don't post it here but rather edit you answer ... And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer uses bad practice, you should pass a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to your component if it's inside a list:

```
Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => <YourComponent key={i} />)
```

- `Array(10)`: Create an empty array that can hold 10 values (replace `10` with a dynamic value in your code).
- `.fill(0)`: Fill it with some dummy value like `0`. The array is now populated with `0` 10 times.
- `.map((_, i) => (...))`: Transform an array of `0` to an array of `YourComponent`. You can change the name of an unused argument to `_` to remove the the [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) warning from ESLint.

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Star } from "@material-ui/icons";

class Points extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      points: 6
    };
  }

  getUserStars() {
    let i = 0;
    let stars = [];
    while (i < this.state.points) {
      i++;
      stars.push(<Star />);
    }
    return stars;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.getUserStars(this.state.points)}</div>;
  }
}

export default Points;
```

You just need to iterate an loop and collect stars in array and call that function in render so whenever state will get updated that function will call and stars will update.