# I'm working on a notes app. How do I get a new Note component to be added on each button click?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to display a new Note component in my app on each button click

I have tried this but it is not producing the desired result

```
class App extends React.Component{
 constructor() {
   super()
   this.state = {}
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

handleClick() {
   return <Note />
}

 render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className = 'header'>
          <h2>ReactJS Notes App</h2>
          <button><i className="fas fa-plus-circle" onClick = 
           {this.handleClick}></i></button>
        </div>

        <Note />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expect that whenever the button is clicked a new Note component will be added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small example of one way that you could achieve what you need. Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pwqk3kjprx?fontsize=14).

In this solution you can fill an array with information that you need to pass in the `Note` component, then loop over the array and render `Note` with the props in the state. I'm just passing a dummy string but you can expand the logic depending on your needs.

If you don't need any props passed to the Note component you can just have a counter and increment it on each click, and simply render `Note` as many times as you need. As Thomas' response above.

Also please note that you may want to put the `onClick` on the `button` instead of the `i` element, that way the note will be added when you click on the button not on the text of the button.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notes: []
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const currentNotes = this.state.notes;

    // you can have an array here that you keep the props
    // to pass into Note component
    currentNotes.push({ noteProp1: "something" });
    this.setState({
      notes: currentNotes
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>ReactJS Notes App</h2>
        <button className="fas fa-plus-circle" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <i>Button</i>
        </button>
        {this.state.notes.map((noteProps, key) => (
          <Note key={key} info={noteProps} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better approach, in the line of my updated answer. You are better off storing your notes data as state as this answer does

Answer (score 0):

this is not quite the right approach. I would suggest you do something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{

 state = {
   numberOfNotes: 1
 }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      numberOfNotes: prevState.numberOfNotes + 1
    });
  };

 render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className = 'header'>
          <h2>ReactJS Notes App</h2>
          <button><i className="fas fa-plus-circle" onClick = 
           {this.handleClick}></i></button>
        </div>

        {Array(this.state.numberOfNotes).fill('arbitrary stuff').map(<Note />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Have a look at this one: [React to render dynamically a certain number of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898165/react-to-render-dynamically-a-certain-number-of-components)

Comment: Hi, I see. I updated my answer a bit so that Array does a map after. What I would suggest you do is to store the data of each note in your App. This would be much cleaner. Then you would have `this.state = { noteData: [] };` And in your code `{this.state.noteData.map(data => <Note props={data} />)}`